# tidyr::pivot_wider() error ! Can't subset columns that don't exist

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm not sure why I keep getting this error but if you have any insight it would be greatly appreciated. The error keeps happening at the `tidyr::pivot_wider` section.
Below is the full code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

impacts = impact %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(PI_Direct_Impact:E_Total,
                        names_to = "names",
                        values_to = "values") %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      Impact_Type = dplyr::case_when(
        stringr::str_detect(names, "PI_") ~ "Income Impacts",
        stringr::str_detect(names, "TV_") ~ "Total Value Added",
        stringr::str_detect(names, "O_") ~ "Output Impacts",
        stringr::str_detect(names, "E_") ~ "Employment Impacts"
      )
    ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      Group = dplyr::case_when(
        stringr::str_detect(names, "Direct_Impact") ~ "Direct",
        stringr::str_detect(names, "Indirect_Impact") ~ "Indirect",
        stringr::str_detect(names, "Induced_Impact") ~ "Induced",
        stringr::str_detect(names, "Total") ~ "Total"
      )
    ) %>%
    dplyr::select(-names) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(
      id_cols = c(
        fips,
        `Economic Category`,
        `Species Category`,
        spec_no,
        Impact_Type,
        Group,
        Imports
      ),
      names_from = Group,
      values_from = values
    )
```

I cannot share the data but here are the column headers right before the `pivot_wider` function:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
   fips `Economic Category` Species~1 spec_no Imports values Impac~2 Group
  <dbl> <chr>               <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
```

This is the full error that I keep getting:

```
Error in `select_wider_id_cols()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Group` doesn't exist.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is missing values (empty cells) in the data. More specifically, the `Group` variable cannot have any empty cells because each level of this variable is going to be a column in you reshaped data and a tibble cannot have any column with missing column names.

Comment: Add this layer to the code and see if solves the problem: `filter(!is.na(Group))` right before `pivot_wider()` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need the `Group` in `id_cols`

```
...
%>%
tidyr::pivot_wider(
      id_cols = c(
        fips,
        `Economic Category`,
        `Species Category`,
        spec_no,
        Impact_Type,
        
        Imports
      ),
      names_from = Group,
      values_from = values
    )
```

According to `?pivot_wider`

> id_cols -  A set of columns that uniquely identifies each observation. Defaults to all columns in data **except** for the columns specified in **names_from and values_from**. Typically used when you have redundant variables, i.e. variables whose values are perfectly correlated with existing variables.

---

The error is reproducible in the documentation example

```
# without specifying id_cols
> fish_encounters %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = station, values_from = seen) %>%
  head
# A tibble: 6 × 12
  fish  Release I80_1 Lisbon  Rstr Base_TD   BCE   BCW  BCE2  BCW2   MAE   MAW
  <fct>   <int> <int>  <int> <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 4842        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2 4843        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
3 4844        1     1      1     1       1     1     1     1     1     1     1
4 4845        1     1      1     1       1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 4847        1     1      1    NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 4848        1     1      1     1      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# with specifying id_cols and names_from the same column
> fish_encounters %>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c(fish, station), names_from = station, values_from = seen)
Error in `select_wider_id_cols()`:
! Can't select columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `station` doesn't exist.
```